# Trying to populate jquery with a php file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get some javascript similar like this

```
var locations = [
     ['Title A', 3.180967,101.715546, 1],
     ['Title B', 3.200848,101.616669, 2],
     ['Title C', 3.147372,101.597443, 3],
     ['Title D', 3.19125,101.710052, 4]
];
```

All the location data is dynamicly created by a .php file. I am calling the php file with ajax like so

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        //dataType: "json",
        url:"/search.php",
        data: {posLat: lat, posLng: lng},
        success:function(returned_data){

        var jsonRes = JSON.parse(returned_data);
        console.log("JSON "+jsonRes[0].routelength)

        $.each(jsonRes , function( index, obj ) {
            var tempArr = [];
            $.each(obj, function( key, value ) {
            console.log(value);
            tempArr.push(value);
            });
            locations.push(tempArr);
            });

          console.log("locations" +locations);

          }
        })
```

but now all the locations data is just one big string and not [...],[...],[...]

The returned_data looks like

```
[ {
    "routeTitle":"Route 1",
    "routelength":9.15,
    "startPointLat":"52.16259353572091",
    "startPointLon":"4.500060081481934"
  },

  {

    "routeTitle":"station",
    "routelength":3.96,
    "startPointLat":"52.16537734384885",
    "startPointLon":"4.483022689819336"
   }, 
  { 
     "routeTitle":"small",
     "routelength":3.15,
     "startPointLat":"52.154267396622025",
     "startPointLon":"4.486691951751709"
  }
]
```

EDIT the ajax part and i am able to get the [[...],[...],[...]] format but it doesn't seem to parse/cast as an array

```
success:function(returned_data){
                    var routes_data=returned_data;
                    var jsonRes = JSON.parse(returned_data);
                    $.each(jsonRes, function(index, val) {
                        var tempArr = [];
                        //routes2.push(jsonRes[index].val);
                        tempArr.push("'"+val.routeTitle+"'");
                        tempArr.push(val.startPointLat);
                        tempArr.push(val.startPointLon);
                        tempArr.push(999);                      
                        tempArr.push("'"+val.routelength+"'");
                        locations2.push("["+tempArr+"]");
                     });
                    locations = "["+locations2+"]";
                    //locations =[['Test title',52.154267396622025,4.486691951751709,999,'3.15'],['Route 1',52.16259353572091,4.500060081481934,999,'9.15'],['station',52.16537734384885,4.483022689819336,999,'3.96']];
                    console.log("locations " +locations);
                    createMarkerV3(map,locations);  
                     }
```

Answer (score 2):

try putting `header('Content-type: application/json');` in the php.

The browser will then expect raw json data and will parse automatically so you wont need 
`JSON.parse` in the javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a long shot here and think maybe this? I don't know if i fully understood.

```
<script>
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($phpData); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: sorry i hit the enter to soon.

Answer (score 0):

This should satisfy your need,

```
var xSrc = [{....}]; //DATA given by you

var xTarget = [];
var xTemp = [];

$.each(xSrc,function(Index,ArrayVal){
    $.each(ArrayVal,function(key,val){
        xTemp.push(val);       
    });

    xTarget.push(xTemp);
    xTemp = [];
});

alert(JSON.stringify(xTarget));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HcfMJ/)

Comment: thanks trying it out, but how can i make the last data item also with quotes?

Comment: This is the json i got, i forgot the last data item routelength. A function i am using seem to only work when routelength is a string. Might edit the function as routelength should be a number {"routeTitle":"Route 1","startPointLat":"52.16259353572091","startPointLon":"4.500060081481934","zindex":909,"routelength":9.15}

Comment: Ok, i think i got the format right. But calling the function like so locations2 = JSON.stringify(xTarget); createMarkerV3(map,locations2); doesn't work. If however i set the console.log output to variable locations2, the function works as expected???

Comment: @rajaprablu no errors. As i said when i copy paste the console output and use it, the function works. But with a reference it doesn't